# Css multilevel menu scrollbar on each level

Tags: html, css

This is what I want to do:

[image: Want to do]

Actually thats something that I want to do, but I am still here: http://jsfiddle.net/sadaf2605/74jYb/

When I try to add scrollbar using over flow this is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/sadaf2605/74jYb/2/

Html:

```
<div id="top_cssmenu" style="float:left;">
          <div id='cssmenu' >
          <ul class="cssmenu1">

             <li data-url="news.html" class='active has-sub'><a>Bangladeshi</a>
              <ul class="cssmenu2">
                   <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                    <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>
                   </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>


                          <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>


                     </li>
                     <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>

                     </li>
                                      <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li><li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
              </ul>
              </li>


             <li class='has-sub menu_news'><a href='#'>West Bengal</a>
                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                   <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                      <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>
                   </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>


                          <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>


                     </li>
                     <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>

                     </li>
                </ul>   

             </li>
             <li class='has-sub menu_news'><a href='#'>Other</a>
                <ul class="cssmenu2">
                   <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                      <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>
                   </li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li><li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>
                    <li data-url="news.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a></li>


                          <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>


                     </li>
                     <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>            
             </li>

             <li data-url="gallery.html" class="has-sub menu_gallery"><a href='#'><span>Gallery</span></a>
              <ul class="cssmenu2">
                   <li data-url="gallery.html"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                      <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>

                   </li>
                    <li data-url="gallery.html" class="has-sub"><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>


                          <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="gallery.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="gallery.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>


                     </li>
                     <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist Name</a>
                        <ul class="cssmenu3">
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                               <li data-url="news.html" ><a href='#'>Artist sub</a></li>
                          </ul>
                     </li>
                </ul>

             </li>

          </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul{
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#cssmenu ul{
    width: 200px;
}
#cssmenu ul, ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu .cssmenu1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu .cssmenu1 li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li.active,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul

 {
  visibility: visible;

}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
/* Custom Stuff */
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  font-weight: 600;

}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {

}
#cssmenu li {
background-color: #2c2a2a;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4a4c;
}
#cssmenu li:hover,
#cssmenu li.active {
  background-color: #535456;
  color:green; 
}

#cssmenu .active {
  color: #97d221;
  background-color: #535456;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > a,
#cssmenu li.active > a {
  color: #97d221;
  background-color: #535456;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #707071;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 16px 8px 16px 28px;
  width: 164px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  max-height:360px;

}

#cssmenu ul ul ul{
  max-height: 361px;

}


#cssmenu ul ul li {
  background: #2c2a2a;
  color: #2c2a2a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4a4c;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
  background: #4a5662;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  color: #707071;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a span {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  top: 0px; 
  left: 99%;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active > ul {
  visibility: visible; /* show sub menu */
}
```

What can be done now?

Comment: I changed `overflow-x: auto` to `hidden` in `#cssmenu ul ul` and that seemed to get you closer to the desired result.

Comment: But then there is a whole level of menu which is just beside hidden due to overflow-x:hidde. :(

Comment: Maybe just display third level elements below, accordion-style.